# Run virtual iOS on windows and install an app

Tags: macos, virtual-machine, iphone, ios

For reasons unknown, I would like to run a virtual iOS environment on my windows computer. Inside of this environment, I need to be able to install a specific app from the app store, be able to run it, and be able to connect to the internet to use it.

I have no idea if this is possible.

I understand the xCode offers a iOS simulator. I can easily VM OSX on this computer. Hardware and speed are no issue.

My question is, if I VM into OSX, and run the iOS sim, will I be able to install apps to it? Can I add apps to it before hand by downloading them to the computer? Will I be able to connect to the internet on the sim? Will I be able to use apps on the sim?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't, a binary app for simulator is different to binary app for app store. You can install apps on simulator only if .app file is signed for simulator, you need the code, build and install.

Comment: What if I were to emulate android on my computer, and use iEMU on the android system to emulate an iOS app?

Comment: Nevermind, I just realized the app I want to use exists on android too... lol... So I'll just use android since its not locked down like a prison.

Comment: LOL! Android is more flexible than iOS